# Need your guidance in using mythrill

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets, ethereum-classic

I am using mythrill for analysing vulnerabilities in smart contract.

Source: https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril

How many user request for analysing can mythrill python code can handle at a time ?

Is it single request or 'N' number of request?

Comment: mythril is a command line tools, so it should support as many users as the hardware allows. There's mythrilX that is service provided by Consensys, in that case you should ask their customer support to clear any doubts.

Comment: Sure Ismael. Thanks for your inputs